# Which location is better saving nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

I have been working with nginx for some time and a little confused by multiple location where the nginx.conf scan be saved. I know the nginx.conf can be saved to 2 locations:

1. /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
2. /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Which location is better saving nginx.conf? Any difference with different location?

Comment: Those are TWO different installations. 1st is from apt-get install, the 2nd from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the configuration file is named **nginx.conf** and placed in the directory */usr/local/nginx/conf*, */etc/nginx* (default for ubuntu), or */usr/local/etc/nginx*.
But you need to keep in mind that nginx can be installed in any directory, for example in the case of assembly from source. In you case - */opt/nginx/conf*.

**nginx.conf** - general config of all server(it is possible to call it an entry point), there as a rule [includes](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) everything that placed in **site-enabled** and **conf.d**

**conf.d** - settings of individual parts or nginx modules, grouped for greater convenience.

**site-available** - configs of individual applications, services, sites and e.t.c. (the fact that they are here - does not mean that they will be included)

**sites-enabled** - here only enabled sites/apps/services. Here symlinks from 
**site-available** are added, in order to quickly enable or disable some config.

Comment: Which config nginx will pick for execution when multiple config presented? I use nginx.conf most of time. But notice the reverse proxy usually save the config under /etc/nginx/sites-available/

Comment: in **nginx.conf** as a rule there is a line `include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;` or ' include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`, which includes all configuration files(in the first case with the *conf* extension) from /etc/nginx/sites-available/ in alphabetical order.